# django user authentication, shoulid admin be used or created from view?

Tags: django, authentication, django-admin, django-views

I am completely new to Django.  I have done all the tutorials and would now like to create a simple user authentication to be able to access a page in my site.

My question is as to whether I should use the admin authentication?  Or should I create my own customer view with a user name and password and use the DJango authentication api?

To clarify, I have a page that I want secured and to only be view when a user has permission to view it.  Is this a reasonable thing to do in the built in Django admin?  It seems the Django admin is for giving permission to create new records related to an apps model.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer using Django's built in authentication system. Lets assume that you'd want to create you own customer model with say mobile number and twitter handle, you can extend Django's User model by following

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Customer(User):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

In this case not only would you inherit attributes like email, username etc from Django's User model but you'll also add you custom attributes that you can store in database.

The easiest approach to securing your pages would be to use [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator. Also take care of including right URLs while securing your pages to make sure you have included Django's login and logout URLs